# how to Launch a spider from django admin action

Tags: django, scrapy

I'm developing a simple web application in Django, and I wanted to start a Scrapy spider from an admin action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with integrating a normal task management process with your django project, see  [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) package:

> Celery is a simple, flexible and reliable distributed system to
>   process vast amounts of messages, while providing operations with the
>   tools required to maintain such a system.

Also, see [how to use celery with django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Then, I'd create a celery task where `Scrapy` is invoked, see:

- [Running Scrapy spiders in a Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528739/running-scrapy-spiders-in-a-celery-task)
- [Run Scrapy from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)
- [How to run Scrapy from within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437402/how-to-run-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script)
- [Scrapy run from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100310/scrapy-run-from-python)

Also see:

- [django-dynamic-scraper](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I installed (celery , django_celery and  RabbitMQ) . and my first ts=est with celery didn't work (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) . when I Call the task in python shell it return "no module named tasks" .

Comment: @Athari it's a separate problem - better start a new thread and provide error details. Thanks.