# Calling Scrapy Spider from script -- cannot turn reactor off?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Very similar to this thread: [Scrapy crawl from script always blocks script execution after scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777910/scrapy-crawl-from-script-always-blocks-script-execution-after-scraping/14802526#14802526), I cannot get anything to work after the reactor.run() line. I've read nearly every SO post on the topic and as you can see from the commented code, I've tried several things including what's recommended in the documentation. Is there something I'm not catching? Maybe something wrong with the parse_item method? It's driving me crazy!

```
class EmailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "email_scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["somedomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.somedomain.com"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_items')]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel=Selector(response)
        results=[]
        item=EmailScraperItems()
        item['title']=sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        item['url']=response.url
        item['email']=sel.re(r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b")
        if item['email'] != []:
            print item['email']
            print item['url']
            if any('info' in email for email in item['email']):
                results.append(item)
                raise CloseSpider('info email found')
            else:
                results.append(item)      

        print results

def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()

dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
spider = EmailSpider(domain='knechtproperties.com')
#settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(Settings())

#crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()

print "this will not print"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this thread: [Scrapy run from script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18793904/1438637). Apparently log.start() masks printing. I'll need to lookup more details on how that works, but for now commenting it out solved the issue.