# how to use scrapy in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, scrapy

Kind of like this question:
[Scrapy debug using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863713/scrapy-debug-using-visual-studio)

but how to import the whole project to VS, if using open solution, obviously there is no solution for the project...

I only know to create a Scrapy using cmd line like:

```
scrapy startproject proj_name
```

so I can get example files, but how to import these to VS?

Answer (score -1):

I know that it is too late.

I think that you mean something like include file in your project.

You can create a new solution and move your files to it under your solution folder then (project --> show all files).

You will then find all the file in the solution after that mark the root of your files then (project --> include in project).

It is explained more obvious in this: ([Undo VS 'Exclude from project'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352554/undo-vs-exclude-from-project))