# Scrapy crawlers not running simultaneously from Python script

Tags: python, command-line, scrapy

I was just wondering why this might be occurring. Here is my Python script to run all:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

file = open('cityNames.txt', 'r')
cityNames = file.read().splitlines()

for city in cityNames:
    url = "http://" + city + ".website.com"
    output = city + ".json"

    cmdline.execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'backpage_tester', '-a', "start_url="+url, '-o', ""+output])
```

cityNames.txt:

```
chicago
sanfran
boston
```

It runs the through the first city fine, but then stops after that. It doesn't run sanfran or boston - only chicago. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is using synchronous calls. You should use asynchronous calls in Python (asyncio?) or use a bash script that iterates over a text file of your urls:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -0 -I{} scrapy crawl spider_name -a start_url={}
```

this should issue one scrapy process per url. However, be warned-- this could easily overload your system if those crawls are extensive and deep on each site, and your spiders are not properly configured.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I got it going. I have 210 scrapers running simultaneously on two different systems. Sometimes they work fine, but sometimes a random handful of output files are empty. I'm not sure why, and it seems like I need to do a lot of debugging. -.-

Comment: @Matt I created a [pip package](http://arachne.readthedocs.org) to run scrapy spiders simultaneously using a flask API. You can check it out