# How to run and save scrapy state from a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

In scrapy projects, we can get persistence support by defining a job directory through the JOBDIR setting for eg.

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

But how to do the same when running spiders using scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess from a python script as answered in  [How to run Scrapy from within a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437402/how-to-run-scrapy-from-within-a-python-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your reference question points out you can pass settings to CrawlerProcess instance.

So all you need to do is pass `JOBDIR` setting:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'JOBDIR': 'crawls/somespider-1'  # <----- Here
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am trying to do a sitemap spider, and it keeps saying "Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml>"

However, there are GBs of requests in the requests.queue file. Why is Scrapy not using those, but instead starting with sitemap? If it filters out the only starting url I give it, it'll never find anything!