# Scrapy throws an error when run using crawlerprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in python using scrapy to collect the name of different posts and their links from a website. When I execute my script from command line it works flawlessly. Now, my intention is to run the script using `CrawlerProcess()`. I look for the similar problems in different places but nowhere I could find any direct solution or anything closer to that. However, when I try to run it as it is I get the following error:

> from stackoverflow.items import StackoverflowItem
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stackoverflow'

This is my script so far (`stackoverflowspider.py`):

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from stackoverflow.items import StackoverflowItem
from scrapy import Selector
import scrapy

class stackoverflowspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping']

    def parse(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        for link in sel.xpath("//*[@class='question-hyperlink']"):
            item = StackoverflowItem()
            item['name'] = link.xpath('.//text()').extract_first()
            item['url'] = link.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            items.append(item)
        return items

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
    })
    c.crawl(stackoverflowspider)
    c.start()
```

`items.py` includes:

```
import scrapy

class StackoverflowItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the tree:
[Click to see the hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abQQO.jpg)

> I know I can bring up success this way but I am only interested to accomplish the task with the way I tried above:

```
def parse(self,response):
    for link in sel.xpath("//*[@class='question-hyperlink']"):
        name = link.xpath('.//text()').extract_first()
        url = link.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
        yield {"Name":name,"Link":url}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @Dan-Dev showed me a way to the right direction, I decided to provide a complete solution which worked for me flawlessly.

With changing nothing anywhere other than what I'm pasting below:

```
import sys
#The following line (which leads to the folder containing "scrapy.cfg") fixed the problem
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\stackoverflow')
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from stackoverflow.items import StackoverflowItem
from scrapy import Selector
import scrapy


class stackoverflowspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping']

    def parse(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        for link in sel.xpath("//*[@class='question-hyperlink']"):
            item = StackoverflowItem()
            item['name'] = link.xpath('.//text()').extract_first()
            item['url'] = link.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            items.append(item)
        return items

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
    })
    c.crawl(stackoverflowspider)
    c.start()
```

***Once again, Including the following within the script fixed the problem***

```
import sys
#The following line (which leads to the folder containing "scrapy.cfg") fixed the problem
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\stackoverflow')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a python path problem.
The easiest way is to call it setting the python path explicitly i.e. from the directory containing scrapy.cfg (and more importantly the stackoverflow module) run:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python3 stackoverflow/spiders/stackoverflowspider.py
```

This sets the python path to include the current directory (.).

for alternatives see https://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/