# How can i assign the returned Scrapy data to a Variable?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

class Livescores2(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'Home'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/football/turkey/super-lig/?tz=3&table=league-home')

    def parse(self, response):

        for total in response.css('td'):
            yield{
                'total': total.css('::text').get()               
                }

                  

runner2 = CrawlerRunner()
runner2.crawl(Livescores2)
```

When i adjust settings like below, i can save the data as json without a problem.

```
runner2 = CrawlerRunner(settings = {
    "FEEDS": {
    "Home.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},
    },
    })
```

I want to assign the returned Scrapy data to a Variable so i can work on it.
I don't want any Json data!

I tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

class Livescores2(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'Home'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/football/turkey/super-lig/?tz=3&table=league-home')

    def parse(self, response):

        for total in response.css('td'):
            yield{
                'total': total.css('::text').get()               
                }

                  

runner2 = CrawlerRunner()
a = runner2.crawl(Livescores2) 

print(a)
```

Result is:
<Deferred at 0x65cbfb6d0>

How can i reach the data from a variable? I develop a Android app so i don't need any Json file.
I don't know how to use "return" function on this code.

Thanks very much

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564312/python-scrapy-how-to-pass-the-response-to-the-main-function-from-the-spider/70566579#70566579).

Comment: I reviewed it. I have a code [link](https://pastecode.io/s/mnrwwui8) It has loop system and 3 spoders so i could not fix the problem with that solunation. I am a newbei in Python so should i use beautifulsoup or mechanicalsoup for this? Scrap always exports json file. Is there a basic metod for this? Too complex i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a class attribute that stores the `data`, and then access it once the spider has completed processing all of the requests. This isn't really the workflow that the `scrapy` framework targets though, and there are likely other web-scraping tools that could handle this more intuitively.

for example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

class Livescores2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Home'
    data = []   # data attribute
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/football/turkey/super-lig/?tz=3&table=league-home')

    def parse(self, response):
        for total in response.css('td'):
            item = {'total': total.css('::text').get()}
            self.data.append(item)  # append item to data list
            yield item

runner2 = CrawlerRunner()
a = runner2.crawl(Livescores2) 

print(Livescores2.data)  # print the collected data
```

Comment: Thanks very much one more question. When i run this code, no results seen on the terminal until i press CTRT  C,  otherwise it stays on hold like this C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Bot>c:/Users/Messi/Desktop/Bot/Scripts/python.exe "c:/Users/Messi/Desktop/Bot/whiskyscraper/whiskyscraper/spiders/Home copy.py" When i press CRTL C all list comes to screen What is the reason of this?

Comment: @MecraYavçın  That isn't the case when I I run it this way...